# How to reduce query time for large dataset with multiple filter variants?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

We have a side panel like flipkart where there are multiple filters applied over, say a dataset of colleges, where different filter options are showing their particular counts. Now the counts of categories has to be shown beside each filter options for we need to query over the large dataset several times resulting to a big deal of latency faced by users. How to optimize such query for greater efficiency?

We are sharing a miniature version of query we just need some suggestion to optmize it.

---

```
SELECT 
    colleges.id as college_id,
                            colleges.approvals as college_approvals,
                            colleges.hash_id as college_hash_id, 
                            courses.id as course_id, 
                            colleges.name as college_name, 
                            ci_states.name as state_name, 
                            ci_cities.name as city_name, 
                            colleges.ranking as college_ranking, 
                            colleges.ranking_info as college_ranking_info, 
                            colleges.college_image as college_image, 
                            colleges.college_logo as college_logo, 
                            courses.course_name as course_name, 
                            courses.course_duration as course_duration, 
                            courses.course_eligibility as course_eligibility,
                            exams.name as exam_accepted,
                            colleges.slug as slug,
                            FORMAT(course_fee_details.amount,0) as course_fee,
                            groupeca.MaxTotalRank as total_rank,
    (SELECT (SELECT name FROM agency WHERE id = agency_id) as agency_name FROM college_agencies WHERE college_id = groupeca.college_id AND total_rank = groupeca.MaxTotalRank GROUP BY college_id) as agency_name
FROM 
    `colleges` 
JOIN 
    courses ON colleges.id = courses.college_id
JOIN
    ci_states ON colleges.state_id = ci_states.id
JOIN
    ci_cities ON colleges.city_id = ci_cities.id
LEFT JOIN
    exams ON courses.exam_accepted_id = exams.id
LEFT JOIN
    course_fee_details ON courses.id = course_fee_details.course_id
LEFT JOIN
    college_agencies ON colleges.id = college_agencies.college_id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT college_id,MAX(total_rank) AS MaxTotalRank FROM college_agencies GROUP BY college_id) groupeca ON college_agencies.college_id = groupeca.college_id AND college_agencies.total_rank = groupeca.MaxTotalRank
WHERE colleges.is_deleted = 0 AND course_fee_details.type = 'general' AND courses.is_deleted = 0 GROUP BY courses.college_id;
```

We have gone through various stackoverflow posts but those aren't relevent to our specific use cases.

### **
EXPLAIN FOR OUR QUERY

** :
[image: EXPLAN for the query mentioned]

Comment: "Multiple filters" might be the cause, but you did not show any of the multiple filters, just the one that makes sure not to select  deleted records.

Comment: You need to update your question with the actual SQL, the ddl for the tables, including any indexes, and also include the EXPLAIN PLAN for the actual query you are running

Comment: @NickW I have updated my question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where's the counting done?  After fetching all the data?  What columns are you counting?

Remove "deleted" entries; this will make the queries a little easier to optimize.

Combine city and state.  Will you be filtering on city and/or state?  I need to see how that is being done so I can explain further.

How big is the set of tables?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM do you have?

Are you grabbing the counts via AJAX?  It might be useful for the "user experience" to bring up the page without the counts, while sending off an asynchronous request (via AJAX) to get the counts.  Then, while the user is distracted by the page loading, you are gathering the counts in parallel.  Furthermore, if there are different sets of counts, it *may* be better to have multiple counts coming back via separate AJAX calls.

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of the tables in the counting query.  Large text columns may need to be moved to other tables to avoid certain inefficiencies.

To do the counting you *may* need to build a separate table with all the filtering in a single table.  (Again, I need more details to discuss further.)

**innodb_buffer_pool_size is 16777216**

This is a very old default, increase it!  With that small a value, any database with more than a trivial number of rows will be very I/O-bound, thereby taking a long time to run.  How much RAM do you have?  Are the tunables in a file called `my.cnf.`?

Comment: Actually for different filter options selected the counts are changing. So the query has to run over each filter parameters selected. The `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is 16777216. The counts are grabbed by ajax as you mentioned.

Comment: @NACHIKETACHAKRABORTY - 16M -- Ouch!  Increase that value (in `my.cnf`).

Comment: Actually client is using shared server can we optimize the query somehow I have already updated my original query.

Comment: @NACHIKETACHAKRABORTY - "Shared server"?  How much RAM?  What other apps are running (other than MySQL)?  How much "free" memory is there?  Is it "swapping"?

Comment: The Ram is 8gb.

Comment: Change the buffer_pool setting to 4G.